# MongoDB UpdateMany query TimeOut

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I'm trying to add a field to the existing collection in mongoDB (It has around 100k documents), when I'm using updateMany to add this, the request is updating a few records (around 2k) and facing TimeOut.

```
MongoServerError: Request timed out.
```

I've checked in the official MongoDB documentation and I can see there's an existing maxTimeMS function for the Cursor object but not for the updateMany. I tried to update using the cursor but it was very very slow.

```
db.myCollection.find({}).forEach(
//update logic here
)
```

What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: What is the write concern?

Comment: Did you try [bulkWrite](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) function? You can use the cursor getting documents in batch and perform a bulkWrite operation with no-ordering and {writeConcern: w: 1, j: true}